# Set global variable of class from inside a promise Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, rxjs, es6-promise

I am facing a weird issue in assigning response to a class's global variable from inside a observable. So my program logic is as follows:

1. Get latest playlists ID's from elastic search (i use elastic search from a type definition file). This returns me a PromiseLike to which i hook a then operator.
2. Inside the promise resolution, i make another http get call (i.e an observable)
3. In Observable subscription, i assign my global array with the response from the server.

Code is working correctly, I am getting responses as they should be but i cant assign the variable to the global one.

Here is my code:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {PlaylistService} from '../api/services'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-playlists',
    templateUrl: './playlists.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./playlists.component.css']
})
export class PlaylistsComponent implements OnInit {
    public playlists: any[] = [];

    constructor(private playlistService: PlaylistService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        let that = this;
        this.playlistService.listIds().then((val) => { // <-- promise resolution
            return this.playlistService.getByIds(val).toPromise(); // <-- http get call which i then convert to promise for simplicity
        }).then((res) => {  // <-- resolution of the http get call
            console.log(this.playlists); <-- in this log, i get my desired results
            // here is my problem, this assignment doesn't happens
            this.playlists = res.data;  
        });
    }
}
```

The listIds function is as follows:

```
listIds() {
    return this.api.listing('playlist').then((body) => {
      let hits = body.hits.hits;
      return _.keys(_.groupBy(hits, '_id'));
    });
}
```

and here is my api.listing function (elastic search client)

```
listing(type: string) {
    let es = this.prepareES();
    return es.search({
            index: 'test',
            _source: ["_id"],
            type: type
    });
}
```

The return type of es.search is

> search(params: SearchParams): PromiseLike>;

Any ideas why i am not being able to assign value to global variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the promise returned by `this.playlistservice.listIds()` doesn't run inside Angulars zone. This is why Angular2 doesn't run change detection and doesn't recognize the change.

You can invoke change detection explicitly after the change:

```
 constructor(private playlistService: PlaylistService, private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {
```

...

```
   ngOnInit() {
        let that = this;
        this.playlistService.listIds().then((val) => { // <-- promise resolution
            return this.playlistService.getByIds(val).toPromise(); // <-- http get call which i then convert to promise for simplicity
        }).then((res) => {  // <-- resolution of the http get call
            console.log(this.playlists); <-- in this log, i get my desired results
            // here is my problem, this assignment doesn't happens
            this.playlists = res.data; 
            this.cdRef.detectChanges(); 
        });
    }
```

Comment: let me check it

Comment: as soon as i added explicit change detection, everything goes as normal, thanks for help man, was stuck in this issue for 2 days

Answer (score 1):

Can you try passing

```
this.playlistService.listIds()
```

call inside your

```
return this.playlistService.getByIds(val)
```

replace val with first service call and see if your view gets updated. Just for testing purpose like

```
return this.playlistService.getByIds(this.playlistService.listIds())
       .then((results)=>{/*rest of logic here*/});
```

Comment: `function(results)` should be `(results)=>` otherwise he won't get the value set at all ;-)

Comment: by the way @GünterZöchbauer what do you think about this way? I mean is it correct to do it like that?

Comment: @noor Because you mentioned that my proposed solution fixed your issue, it was not about the value not being changed but about Angular not recognizing the change. Therefore I don't think this would change anything. An alternative approach would be to use `zone.run(/* code that changes model here */)` which also causes change detection when the passed function is completed. This approach is preferred if the change modifies multiple components, for example if you do a `this.router.navigate()` from a callback that runs outside angulars zone.